# Thunar Quick Link to Downloads not Updating After Changing Default Downloads Directory

Tags: linux, xfce, thunar

I recently updated the default downloads directory on my Linux system by editing the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. The change seems to be reflected in most applications, including Firefox. However, the Thunar file manager's quick link to "Downloads" still points to the original location, i.e. `/home/<username>/Downloads`.

I've tried the following steps, but the issue persists:

1. Logged out and logged back in.
2. Restarted Thunar.
3. Confirmed correct entry for `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR` in `user-dirs.dirs`.
4. Checked and adjusted directory permissions.

Despite these efforts, Thunar continues to point to the old location. Is there a specific configuration file or setting in Thunar that needs to be updated manually, or am I missing something else? In Windows 10, once you move the Downloads folder to a different location, the Downloads link under Quick Access immediately points to the new location.

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**System Details:**

- Operating System: MX Linux 23.1
- Desktop Environment: XFCE
- Thunar Version: 4.18.4

Comment: **Update**: This isn't the case with the Desktop folder. I click on the Quick Link in Thunar and it goes to the new location. Strange! Can somebody confirm this? 
@John Does that mean manually deleting old Downloads folder, replacing it with a symlink to the new location is the only option?

Comment: Did you get this resolved in the end? I am experiencing the same problem. The defined locations in `user-dirs.dirs` aren't showing up and I get the defaults instead, apart from `DESKTOP`.
`

Comment: @paradroid Unfortunately not! :(